# Objective-C foreach for creating a NSDictionary not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to sort a NSDictionary with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
for (NSDictionary* lesson in jsonDict[@"data"][@"lessons"]) {
    data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]][@"title"] = lesson[@"title"];
}
```

If I log the values of `lesson[@"day"]` and so on, the values seem to be correct. Somehow if I log `data[@"1"][@"1"]` after the loop it's just empty. So the problems seems to be setting the values into the NSDictionary data.

The original JSON string contains a list with all lessons. To access them correctly I want to have a new NSDictionary in this format: data[day][index][field]

The JSON code looks like this:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"lessons":[{"id":1,"index":"1","day":"1","title":"Mathe","teacher":"Mr. xyz","room":"103","ind":"1"},{"id":2,"index":"1","day":"2","title":"Physik","teacher":"Mr xyz","room":"PH4","ind":"1"},...
```

Comment: can you post an example of the JSON?

Comment: "reorder a dictionary"?  Say, what?

Comment: [NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @jackslash I added a part of a JSON example, although this is can't be the issue. I can access the data successfully, the problem is just to put this into a new NSDictionary (in the for loop)

Comment: @Desdenova You mean that it's only possible with setvalue for key or something similar? That would be very difficult and complex because I am using a nested/multidimensional array...

Comment: @Dion The thing is you can't modify `NSDictionary` like that, you need a mutable container which in your case is `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Be wary of JSON automatic typing.  "foo":1 and "foo":"1" are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is (I assume) that

```
data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]][@"title"] = lesson[@"title"];
```

does not automatically create the intermediate dictionaries

```
data[lesson[@"day"]]
data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]]
```

You have to check first if they exist, and assign a mutable dictionary if they don't yet
exist. (There is no [Autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) as with Perl hashes!) Something like:

```
if (data[lesson[@"day"]] == nil) {
    data[lesson[@"day"]] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}
if (data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]] == nil) {
    data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}
data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]][@"title"] = lesson[@"title"];
```

---

Complete working code:

```
NSString *str = @"{\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"lessons\":[{\"id\":1,\"index\":\"1\",\"day\":\"1\",\"title\":\"Mathe\",\"teacher\":\"Mr. xyz\",\"room\":\"103\",\"ind\":\"1\"},{\"id\":2,\"index\":\"1\",\"day\":\"2\",\"title\":\"Physik\",\"teacher\":\"Mr xyz\",\"room\":\"PH4\",\"ind\":\"1\"}]}}";
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary* lesson in jsonDict[@"data"][@"lessons"]) {
    if (data[lesson[@"day"]] == nil) {
        data[lesson[@"day"]] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    if (data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]] == nil) {
        data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    data[lesson[@"day"]][lesson[@"index"]][@"title"] = lesson[@"title"];
}
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Output:

```
{
    1 =     {
        1 =         {
            title = Mathe;
        };
    };
    2 =     {
        1 =         {
            title = Physik;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: This looks totally correct and actually was just the thing I was looking for but somehow it does not work either :/ If I take your code entirely there is an error "Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'", and if I change it to setValue:… forKey:… the output is still empty and the content is not written to the new NSDictionary like before :(

Comment: @Dion: The first error message means that you have a (immutable) NSDictionary, instead of a NSMutableDictionary. And you should use `setObject:forKey` to set dictionary values, unless you have specific reasons to use the Key-Value coding method `setValue:forKey:`. - I have tested the code with your input data and it seems to work. See updated answer.

Comment: The reason why it didn't instantly work was my fault. Your answer is totally correct and working :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization creates dictionaries and arrays filled with other dictionaries, arrays, and values of type NSString, NSNumber, or NSNull.

You should re-think your strategy of writing hugely complex lines of code, but extract things one by one, to make it less confusing, and to make it possible to debug. Like

```
NSDictionary* data = jsonDict [@"data"];
NSArray* lessons = data [@"lessons"];

for (NSDictionary* lesson in lessons)
{
    NSString* lessonDay = lesson [@"day"];
    ...
}
```

and so on (it will also make your code run a lot quicker if you don't lookup the same thing again and again and again and again).

Now to where your bug is: dict [@"key"] = data; calls setObject:forKey: . However, dict [@"key1"] [@"key2"] calls objectForKey: @"key1" on the dictionary, that will give you a nil value, and then setObjectForKey: will be called with a nil receiver.

Comment: hm okay thanks for your answer but how exactly is it possible to fix the problem?